# Android : Where is the database sqlite file in hardware device?

Tags: android

I want to get the sqlite file from my SAMSUNG GALAXY TAB, but I dont know where is it? Please help me? 
Thanks a lo.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you visited /data and found nothing in it, and you are examining an ordinary piece of Android hardware, that is expected. DDMS does not have permission to browse through /data.

However, at least if your app is compiled in debug mode, you can use the adb pull command at the console to download your file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[Location of sqlite database on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452538/android-location-of-sqlite-database-on-the-device)

You will find it here:
/data/data/Your-Application-Package-Name/databases/your-database-name

Answer (score 0):

If your device is `not rooted` then you don't have access in `data` folder. Then you should write the database in `sd card`. On rooted device or emulator sqlite file is inside

`/data/data/packagename/databases/`

for not rooted device write file like this

```
private void writeToSD() throws IOException {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String currentDBPath = DB_NAME;
        String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
        File currentDB = new File(DB_PATH, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Where DB_NAME is the name of my database and DB_PATH is defined as follows:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replace("files", "databases") + File.separator;
}
else {
        DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
}
```

And add the following permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Check this question in SO [How to check database on not rooted android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883447/how-to-check-database-on-not-rooted-android-device)