# How to get the live view of inserted data in Sqlite database on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, debugging

Will you please help me with this problem.

I'm inserting values to my Sqlite database.

How can I check or view the inserted data.

Is there is any tool or other techniques to show the data ?

Comment: Search About Content Provider

Comment: you want to see that data in `.db` file or want to show in app?

Comment: your Writing Contacts to log :) @BivinVinod

Comment: Please refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-do-i-view-the-sqlite-database-on-an-android-device

Comment: Get database from data folder using android device monitor. Then open .db file using sqlite browser. Download from this link: http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: @elsunhoty you don't need cross process data sharing just to insert values in sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best Sqlite debugging tool for android application is

> **Stetho** By Facebook

[http://facebook.github.io/stetho/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6UKo.png)

Stetho is a sophisticated debug bridge for Android applications. When enabled, developers have access to the Chrome Developer Tools feature natively part of the Chrome desktop browser. Developers can also choose to enable the optional dumpapp tool which offers a powerful command-line interface to application internals.

***Download*** or **Alternatively you can include Stetho from Maven Central via Gradle or Maven.**

```
 // Gradle dependency on Stetho 
  dependencies { 
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1' 
  } 
  <dependency>
    <groupid>com.facebook.stetho</groupid> 
    <artifactid>stetho</artifactid> 
    <version>1.5.1</version> 
  </dependency>
```

Only the main stetho dependency is strictly required, however you may also wish to use one of the network helpers:

```java
    dependencies { 
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1' 
      }
```

Or

```
 dependencies { 
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.5.1' 
  }
```

Or

```
 dependencies { 
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-urlconnection:1.5.1' 
  }
```

**Integrations**

*Setup*

Integrating with Stetho is intended to be seamless and straightforward for most existing Android applications. There is a simple initialization step which occurs in your `Application class:`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
  }
}
```

This brings up most of the default configuration but does not enable some additional hooks (most notably, network inspection). See below for specific details on individual subsystems.

```
Enable Network Inspection
```

If you are using the popular OkHttp library at the 2.2.x+ or 3.x release, you can use the Interceptors system to automatically hook into your existing stack. This is currently the simplest and most straightforward way to enable network inspection.

**For OkHttp 2.x**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.networkInterceptors().add(new StethoInterceptor());
```

**For OkHttp 3.x**

```
 new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
        .build();
```

As interceptors can modify the request and response, add the Stetho interceptor after all others to get an accurate view of the network traffic.

If you are using `HttpURLConnection`, you can use `StethoURLConnectionManager` to assist with integration though you should be aware that there are some caveats with this approach. In particular, you must explicitly add `Accept-Encoding: gzip` to the request headers and manually handle compressed responses in order for Stetho to report compressed payload sizes.

[image]

[image: Sqlite Databases]
[image]

for more info please visit [stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho)

Answer (score 10):

**If You Want to Show a data on `Log` try below code :**

```
for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);
```

**Other Way to show a `database` see below steps:**

1. Go to `Tools -> DDMS` or click the Device Monitor icon next to SDK Manager in Tool bar.
2. Device Monitor window will open. In File Explorer tab, click `data -> data -> your project name.` After that your databases file will open. Click `pull a file from device icon.` Save the file using .db extension.
3. Open FireFox, Press Alt , `Tools -> SQLiteManager.`
4. Follow Database -> connect to Database -> browse your database file and click ok. Your SQLite file will opened now.

**If you Download a database on `DDMS` then You download**

> DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.10.1-win64

and put the `database` file on this software and you get the data.

---

### NEW UPDATE OF DDMS

- I'll Update My Answer becoz now a days Android Studio update in Android Studio 3.1 or up to other like now 3.2 in this Studio **DDMS** function is not available but Don't Worry i have another solution.
- In your android Studio See right side Bottom Corner there is one Option like **Device File Explorer** Click on this button

After that you can see like below image is open on your screen :

[image]

**Now select `data -> data -> your project name.`  :)**

Answer (score 6):

I can't believe no one's mentioned this but what you are probably looking for is [Android Debug Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database)

Works great with Android Room as well and you can view, edit tables and records.

Answer (score 3):

Although you approved `Cassius Clay's` answer,  if you need to process the raw data

root is not needed ( if it's not on the sdcard follow @Ankit 's answer )

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

arg_folder = sys.argv[1]  # root folder to recursively search db files from
output_lines = subprocess.check_output(['adb', 'shell', ('ls -R %s' % arg_folder)]).decode('utf-8').splitlines()
db_files = []
current_folder = ''
for line in output_lines:
    """
        Output example for 'ls -R /data/data':
            /data/data/org.fdroid.fdroid/files/fdroid/repo/icons:

            /data/data/org.fdroid.fdroid/shared_prefs:
            apks-pending-install.xml
            org.fdroid.fdroid_preferences.xml

            /data/data/ru.meefik.busybox:
            cache
            files
            lib
            shared_prefs

        if line contains '/' it's a directory, we want to extract the full path for '.db' files
    """
    if line.__contains__('/'):
        current_folder = line
    elif line.endswith('.db'):
        db_files.append('%s/%s' % (current_folder[:-1], line))
print("Listing databases..")

while True:
    try:
        for idx, full_path in enumerate(db_files):
            print("{}) {}".format(idx + 1, full_path))
        i = input("Enter database number : ")
        db = db_files[int(i) - 1]  # selected database
        subprocess.check_output(['adb', 'pull', db])  # pulling the .db file from device to local
        db = db.split('/')[-1]  # "/data/data/com.app/folder/private.db".split('/')[-1] = private
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        # getting list of current database tables
        tables = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';").fetchall()
        for table in tables:
            table = table[0]  # little fix, it comes as a tuple
            print('%s%s' % (db[:-2], table))
            with pd.option_context('display.width', 1000):  # setting terminal width to view all table columns inline
                print(pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM %s" % table, conn))  # print table content
            print('- ' * 50)  # table print separator
        # cleanup
        if input('remove database file (from local) [y/N] ? ').lower() == 'y':
            print('removing ', db)
            os.remove(db)
        # repeat
        c = input("Press ENTER to continue or CTRL+C to Quit..")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
```

[image: preview 2..]

Here is a less human-friendly very-long-one-liner

```
read -p "enter root folder to recursively search db files from: " f;dbs=( $(adb shell ls -R $f |
    while read line
    do
        line=$(echo $line | tr -d '\r')
        if [[ "$line" =~ ^/.*:$ ]]
        then
            dir=${line%:}
        elif [[ "$line" = "opendir failed" ]]
        then
            echo "$dir - permission denied"
        else
            if [[ "$dir" = "/" ]]; then dir=""; fi
            echo "$dir/$line" | grep '\.db$'
        fi
    done)
);echo ${dbs[@]}; dbs+=(exit);select db in "${dbs[@]}"; do
  [[ $db == exit ]] && break
  echo "You have chosen $db"
  adb pull $db
  python -c 'import sqlite3;import pandas as pd;db=sqlite3.connect("'${db##*/}'");tables=db.cursor().execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\"table\";").fetchall();print([pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM %s" % t[0], db) for t in tables]);'
done
```

GIF because I'm too lazy to document

[image: preview..]

Answer (score 2):

**DDMS approach is not working in non rooted device**

I follow [How to check database on not rooted android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883447/how-to-check-database-on-not-rooted-android-device/29257875#29257875) to import the Sqlite DB from device to PC.

Follow the given steps:

1. Open the terminal in Android Studio
2. Change default directory to your_path_to>SDK>platform-tools>
3. adb shell run-as [package] chmod 777 /data/data/[package]/databases/

   adb shell run-as [package] chmod 777 /data/data/[package]/databases/[db_file_name]

   adb shell run-as [package] cp /data/data/[package]/databases/[db_file_name] /sdcard/

   adb pull /sdcard/[db_file_name]

4.Check the pulled SQLite DB in folder sdk>platform-tools

Now you can use any SQLite Viewer to view the pulled database.

**Note: Two permissions are required in Manifest file otherwise data will not copied in pulled DB**

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

You can add,edit,check all your DB tables data including your sharedpreferences data with this library (Database debug database)
[Follow this link to install](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database).

All you need to do is to just put the dependency, compile and run the program ,you will find a link like (your_package_name  D/DebugDB: Open http://172.16.6.117:8081 in your browser) in logcat which will show all your DB on browser[image]