# how do i pull databases from third party apps in non rooted device

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

i'm doing a dictionary project and i need some databases from an app in google 
play.but there is no folder in SD card or internal storage that contains databases.is there any way to pull this third party app's databases and use it in project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access sqlite database on android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856210/access-sqlite-database-on-android-device)

Comment: i dont have this third party app project but i want to pull it's databases

Comment: you dont need to. You just have to know the package name

Comment: but there is no folder in adb for accessing my app's database

Comment: Once you have installed application, you need to access the package folder through adb and that is only possible if the debugging is enabled in the application