# Android: Unable to write the SD card from emulator

Tags: android

I'm using windows vista and Eclipse for developing. I write the simple
code to download a file and store it on my sd card. But i'm getting
Exception(File not found exception).
Here is my code

```
 public void downloadNewapk() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(apkURL.toString());
        HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/download/";
        Log.v("log_tag", "PATH: " + PATH);
        File file = new File(PATH);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("log_tag", "Error: " + e);
    }
    Log.v("log_tag", "Check: ");
}
```

I have added user permission in `manifest.xml` 

And i check for SD card status in
`Environment.getExternalStorageState()` it gives as "removed"
But i added 1GB size for my sd card when creating the AVD.
I'm new to android and resolving this is really important to me
Please anyone can help me

Comment: I'd suggest u to remove the emulator and re-create new one. Once it worked for me that way.

Comment: I also accounted the same problem a few days ago.But I have not solved it either.If you solve it , plz let me know.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have emaulator's sdcard created with permissions to write on it.

Refer: [Android Emulator sdcard push error: Read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system/12797483#12797483)

After this step, I believe it shall work for you programatically as well.