# Unable to write files on sdcard android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I am trying to write a MIDI file on SDcard. It works on my device but not in the emulator. Here's the error on the logCat :

```
12-25 09:18:27.733: W/ExternalStorage(1951): Error create /sdcard/download/test.mid
12-25 09:18:27.733: W/ExternalStorage(1951): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/download/test.mid
12-25 09:18:27.733: W/ExternalStorage(1951):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:244)
12-25 09:18:27.733: W/ExternalStorage(1951):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
12-25 09:18:27.733: W/ExternalStorage(1951):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:168)
12-25 09:18:27.733: W/ExternalStorage(1951):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:147)
```

I have set the permission in the manifest file, and change the path from "/sdcard/download/test.mid" to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/download/test.mid" but still doesn't work.

FYI, I use [Kevin Boone's MidiFile](http://kevinboone.net/javamidi.html) class, and here's my code :

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mf.writeToFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/download/test.mid");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first make sure you have the proper permission, if you don't add this to you're AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Secondly you should also check if download folder exist if not you have to create it. Check the method exist from the [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) class.

If you take a look at Kevin's MidiFile method use it only create a file on a specific path it does not ensure the path exist that is your job

```
mg.writeToFile ("somefile.mid");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking if you have emaulator's sdcard is created with permissions to write on it.

Refer this: [Android Emulator sdcard push error: Read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system/12797483#12797483)

Once you are through with this step, I think it shall work for you programatically as well.