# Android:transfer error: Read-only file system

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, android-sdcard

I want to push a *.mp3 file in to my emulator, but it gives me these 2 errors:

```
 transfer error: Read-only file system
 Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
```

To resolve the problem, i have done these works, but still not working:

1-Using CMD to do this: `c:\android-sdk\platform-tools\>abd remount`

2-Add these 2 lines to the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

3-Set the SDcard in emulator configuration as 1024 Mb
[image]

**The thing that makes me wonderful is that the sdcard folder in file explorer has all the necessary permissions**
[image]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007395/how-to-upload-images-in-gallery-of-android-emulator/16007494#16007494 if it helps

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system) helps you :)

Answer (score 23):

Here is a solution I found in other site, which is the only way that worked in my case:

---

In a terminal (I work on Mac OS X) I wnt to sdk/platform-tools directory (to get access to the adb shell) then I typed the following commands:

```
./adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount rootfs / 
chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard
```

and then typed `exit` to exit `su`, and `exit` again to exit the adb shell.

Answer (score 5):

@atisman's answer got me working.  There are two small bits to add to his response though:

First, picky as it seems, you might need an extra '-' in the unix command line, depending on your local OS.  The only way it would work for me was:

```
mount -o -rw,remount rootfs /
```

The other item is to make sure you have actually defined the device's SD card with some size.  I see you have, but I didn't, so just putting it out there in case anyone else has a similar issue.

Open AVD manager, click on the device you are using... click 'edit' and go to the "SD Card" area.  Make sure if "Size" is clicked, that there is a number in the area next to it.  Otherwise the SD card can't hold any info.

Comment: I just put some size in the edit field of the AVD Manager and the read only error has gone but now another one is in. and its like
      :Failed to push the item
      :Null
Any help please?

Comment: Ok got it! It starts working after i restarted my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

if some one have same problem in new build of studio . 0.8.9 and above see my solution and it will work like a charm , here : afra mehrparvar solution in the bottom of the page .

[Android Emulator sdcard push error: Read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system/26676631#26676631)