# Not able to create folder in eclipse for the file-explorer using DDMS perspective

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

### I am trying to create a folder named DCIM in sdcard in the Eclipse using DDMS perspective

---

***I am getting this error, How can i overcome this ?***

[image]

**Thanks !!**

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I found the simplest solution

**This is what i did**::

1. `Window` --- > `AndroidVertualDeviceManager` ----> `select the
   device` ---> `click edit`
2. Then mention the size ...

[image]

3. Go to `DDMS` --- > `sdcard` --> `use push a file onto device`

***Thats it folks PRESTO .... now you can create folder & add files manually***

[good link reference](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/create-sd-card-in-android-emulator-and.html)