# Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': Read-only file system

Tags: android, eclipse

i am following the HelloWorld tutorial from developer.android.com in Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 & 0S X 10.9.4, but when I try to run the application I get the next error:

```
[2014-08-15 14:05:33 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-08-15 14:05:34 - MyFirstApp] Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': Read-only file system
[2014-08-15 14:05:34 - MyFirstApp] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Read-only file system
[2014-08-15 14:05:34 - MyFirstApp] Launch canceled!
```

I guess I have to unmount the /system, but I don't know where is located exactly:

That's the result trying to unmount:

```
mount: /system: unknown special file or file system.
```

same for System:

```
mount: /System: unknown special file or file system.
```

and no result trying to find it using

```
mount | grep system
```

Comment: How did you make the emulator Read-Only? That seems a bit weird and makes it rather impossible to deploy anything to it. Have you tried creating a new device?

Comment: No, you should not have to do anything.  If the emulator is not fully initialized, wait.  Otherwise try making a new emulator.

Comment: I deleted manually the folder /Users/user/.android/avd and create a new device again.

Comment: This should work for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system

Answer (score 0):

1. open CMD
2. Change directory to SDK location (android-sdks\platform-tools)
3. Execute "adb shell"
4. Execute "su"
5. Execute "mount -o remount -o rw /"

Need to do for all (not only /system)